# jQuery: adding multiple images to a div

Tags: jquery

I'm new to jQuery and trying to add several images to a single div simultaneously by selecting multiple image tags:

```
$("#img1").attr("src","static/images/S1.png");
$("#img2").attr("src","static/images/S2.png");
```

The target HTML is:

```
<div id="stim">
   <img id="img1">
   <img id="img2">
</div>
```

I want the two images to be left and right aligned respectively, so the style associated with the images is:

```
#img1 {
  float: left;
  width: 200px;
}

#img2 {
  float: right;
  width: 200px;
}
```

The problem is that only one image is being shown.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you create an example? Try jsFiddle.net. Also, what are `current_img1` and `current_img2`?

Comment: Can you provide some more code,or try on your own to check validity of `current_img1` and `current_img2`

Comment: Without seeing the rest of your code, I'd guess that the problem is almost certainly that the one of the values in `current_imgX` is not valid.

Comment: sorry, should have specified: current_img1 and current_img2 were defined elsewhere. edited the question accordingly. I know that's not the issue, since one of them appears.

Answer (score 0):

My tip is that one of the two imageurls returns httpstate 404 of mybe the container div is styled and not big enough.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work. You can test it in a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6sjtu0u1/), it works just fine.

```
$("#img1").attr("src",current_img1);
$("#img2").attr("src",current_img2);
```

So maybe the image url is wrong or something like that. check out your console (F12) and see if shows up some error